# Remove AWT artifacts from import suggestions

Tags: java, import, netbeans-8

In Netbeans 8, how would I disable the suggestion to import artifacts from the `java.awt` package tree so that import suggestion for only the `javafx.scene` package tree would be shown?

Answer (score 0):

- Open NetBeans and at the top click Tools>Options.
- Go to the Editor tab and choose "Code Completion". 
  Select Java in the language box.
- Where it says "Packages/classes:", choose "Exclude" and click the add button on the right.

I added "java.awt" and "java.awt." without the quotation marks and that worked.

Remember to click apply in the bottom right before you close down the window.
Hope it works for you, it did for me.